# scikit TfidfVectorizer.transform() returns varying results for same document

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm fairly new to `sckit-learn` and am confused because the `TfidVectorizer` is sometimes returning a different vector for the same document.

My corpus contains >100 documents.

I'm running:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2), token_pattern=r'\b\w+\b', min_df=1)

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

to initialize the `TfidVectorizer`and to fit it to the documents in the corpus. `corpus` is a list of text strings.

Afterwards, if I do:

```
test = list(vectorizer.transform([corpus[0]]).toarray()[0])

test == list(X.toarray()[0])
```

The result is `False`.

If I print the first 20 items of `list(X.toarray()[0])` and `test`, respectively, you can see they're off by a fraction, when I expect them to be the same.

```
[0.16971458376720741, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

vs.

```
[0.16971458376720716, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

But if I do:

```
test_1 = list(vectorizer.transform([corpus[0]).toarray()[0])
test_2 = list(vectorizer.transform([corpus[0]).toarray()[0])
test_1 == test_2
```

The result is `True`. Above, I'm essentially calculating the vector twice, which is what I thought I was doing in the first example (since X holds the vectors returned during `fit_transform`).

Why, in my first example, are the vectors different? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Not exactly sure what's happening, some sort of rounding error maybe, I think it's probably not worth worrying about.

Comment: Hmm ok. Yeah was just bothering me. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, it's very likely a rounding error and it's probably not worth *worrying* about.

However I think it's worth trying to understand the phenomenon.

What's probably happening is a rounding error. These errors sometimes happen because numbers on your computer are not of infinite precision: a typical numpy float will be stored on 64bits.

The fact that they are of finite precision means that *addition is no longer associative*: a + (b + c) is not always exactly (a + b) + c.

Let's try to show this behavior in action:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random(size=1000000)
print(a.dtype)
print("%.15f" % a.sum())
b = np.random.permutation(a)
print("%.15f" % b.sum())
```

Output:

```
float64
500399.674621732032392
500399.674621731741354
```

Now if we extend the above script to try with floats on 32 bits:

```
a = a.astype(np.float32)
print(a.dtype)
print("%.15f" % a.sum())
b = np.random.permutation(a)
print("%.15f" % b.sum())
```

We get:

```
float64
500214.871674167399760
500214.871674167283345
float32
500214.937500000000000
500215.000000000000000
```

You can see the error is much higher: that's because floats on 32 bits are less precise than floats on 64 bits.

Now if you think this is awesome and you want to know more, numpy gives you details on the storage of floats through the `np.finfo` function:

```
In [10]: np.finfo(np.float32)
Out[10]: finfo(resolution=1e-06, min=-3.4028235e+38, max=3.4028235e+38, dtype=float32)
```

Sorry I did not answer your question ;). Maybe the cause of the error in your case is not exactly what I explained, I'm writing this because I think if you were familiar with theses errors you would not have asked that question in the first place.

Hope this helps anyway!

Comment: Thanks for this. Since this is probably helpful for others running into this question so I am accepting it as the answer.